# VisualSVN Server - create repository on server from desktop computer

Tags: svn, repository, remote-access, visualsvn-server

I am using VisualSVN Server Standard Edition on a different computer than my development workstation.  Is it possible to create a new repository from my development workstation on the VisualSVN Server machine?  Or, do I have to physically go to that machine to create a new repository?

Comment: @Oberon - I am using TortoiseSVN as well as Subclipse within Aptana Studio.  I wasn't able to add a repository with Subclipse, but I haven't tried with Tortoise.

Comment: @Oberon - I could only find how to make a new repository locally using TortoiseSVN.  How would I got about making a remote repository?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the documentation of [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/remote-admin/) about remote admins is clear:

> Remote Server Administration is one of the key benefits of the VisualSVN Server Enterprise Edition

So that feature is only available with the other edition. Before you decide, you should know what your goals are:

- Provide a SVN repository only for yourself or for others?
- Include some authentication / authorization methods to it?
- ...

Depending on the answers, you will have different options:

- Run a standalone SVN server on the "different workstation" (Windows or Linux?)
- Run apache on the different workstation in front of the repositories.

See the [documentation in the SVN Red Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig) which option is the most appropriate for you.